# Problems with JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: batch-file, path, java-home

I have a simple batch file script that I am attempting to run which is as follows:

```
@echo Starting MI Web Service: Creating CACERTS KeyStore ...
@del certs\cacerts.jks
@"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias foo -keypass foobar123 -keystore certs\cacerts.jks -storepass %1
@"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -delete -alias foo -keystore certs\cacerts.jks -storepass %1
```

When I attempt to run this I am getting an error that the system cannot find the path specified.

Under my environment variables I have added the JAVA_HOME variable and I have update my path variable to include JAVA_HOME as follows:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
PATH = C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%JAVA_HOME%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

Can anyone see why the system would still be failing to find the file?

Comment: The `PATH` should contain the Java `bin` directory ...

Comment: would that be just %JAVA_HOME%\bin; in the location where I currently have it? Does this require a restart of the OS

Comment: @Jay You should never insert folder paths to __PATH__ at beginning. The first folder path should be always `%SystemRoot%\system32` as otherwise every Windows standard executable in protected System32 directory of Windows can be for execution of many applications and scripts replaced by malware executables in none protected folder inserted at beginning of __PATH__.

Comment: @Jay Next on every start of a new process like a batch file a copy of entire environment variables table of current process is made. So if you add `%JAVA_HOME%` to __PATH__ in advanced Windows system settings for current user only or for entire system, you have to exit and restart the process using the batch file. Best would be to code your batch file in a manner not depending on __PATH__ or __JAVA_HOME__. It is not really difficult to find `keytool.exe` with batch code in an indefinite subdirectory of ``%ProgramFiles%\Java\`` or ``%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\``.